# How does one create aligned label-field pairs correctly in Windows Forms Designer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to make a form dialog. I noticed that individual elements can "snap" together, so I made use of that feature to align them.

The purple lines are added by me in Paint and show the approximate lines of the snap feature:

[image]

However, the issue is that I would like to have the fields expand to fill the window. I've also noticed that some forms created this way tend to get broken and overflow:

[image]

How to layout the form so that all fields are aligned with the labels, have the same height and expand to fill the window? At the same time, I also need them to force the window on their minimum size, so that it cannot get smaller than all the fields together.

I tried to "snap" the fields to window edge. It displays the blue snap indicator, but if I resize the window, the field does not resize along with it.

[image]

How to make the form resizable?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, but did you try adding right to the anchor property of the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, no change at all. I tried docking as well, that broke the whole layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using docking, but you will have to add extra panels just to not screw up the layout. It's going to be cumbersome and ugly to design but can look OK at run time.

One way to do it is by docking a panel to the left and have all your labels on it (1), and another on to fill the rest (2).
On that panel, you first dock another panel to the right, as a spacer (3). Then you dock another panel to top (4), and then on that inner panel you dock the Dropdown to bottom.

See attached image:

[image]

Or there is an easier option and that's to use a table layout panel, with 3 columns (left most for the labels, fixed width, middle for the inputs, 100%, and right most as the spacer, again fixed with, and dock the entire table layout panel to fill. Then you don't have to worry about vertical alignment anymore.

Comment: Thanks, this looks a lot like what I want. But How do I make sure that all inputs on the rights side match their labels? Do I have to manually set height to match the labels?

Comment: In this case, yes, but I completely forgot about the table layout panel, check out the last part of my answer I've just edited in.